# error Call to undefined method ControllerPaymentStanbic:: render() in Payment plugin

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway, payment, opencart2.x

I've set up this module for a payment gateway on opencart but i got this error which i changed `$this->data` to `$data`, I get a blank page. If i change it back to $this->data i get this [error](http://prntscr.com/832nd2) http://prntscr.com/832nd2

here is the code

```
                        <?php 
            class ControllerPaymentCipgSim extends Controller {
              private $error = array(); 
              public function index() { 
                $this->load->language('payment/cipg_sim');
                $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
                $this->load->model('setting/setting');
                if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && ($this->validate())) {
                  $this->load->model('setting/setting');
                  $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('cipg_sim', $this->request->post);
                  $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
                  $this->redirect(HTTPS_SERVER .'index.php?route=extension/payment&token=' . $this->session->data['token']);
                }
                $this->data['heading_title']     = $this->language->get('heading_title');
                $this->data['text_enabled']     = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
                $this->data['text_disabled']     = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
                $this->data['text_all_zones']     = $this->language->get('text_all_zones');
                $this->data['text_yes']       = $this->language->get('text_yes');
                $this->data['text_no']         = $this->language->get('text_no');
                $this->data['text_test']       = $this->language->get('text_test');
                $this->data['text_live']       = $this->language->get('text_live');
                $this->data['button_save']       = $this->language->get('button_save');
                $this->data['button_cancel']     = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
                $this->data['tab_general']       = $this->language->get('tab_general');
                $this->data['get_from_aznet']     = $this->language->get('text_get_from_aznet');
                $this->data['set_at_aznet']     = $this->language->get('text_set_at_aznet');
                $this->data['optional_aznet']     = $this->language->get('text_optional_aznet');
                $this->data['text_min_amount']    = $this->language->get('text_min_amount');
                $this->data['text_order_status']  = $this->language->get('text_order_status');
                $this->data['text_custom_html']    = $this->language->get('text_custom_html');
                $this->data['text_custom_html_help']= $this->language->get('text_custom_html_help');
                $this->data['entry_status']     = $this->language->get('entry_status');
                $this->data['entry_login_id']     = $this->language->get('entry_login_id');
                $this->data['entry_transaction_key']= $this->language->get('entry_transaction_key');
                $this->data['entry_response_key']   = $this->language->get('entry_response_key');
                $this->data['entry_minimum_amt']   = $this->language->get('entry_minimum_amt');
                $this->data['entry_server']     = $this->language->get('entry_server');
                $this->data['entry_test']       = $this->language->get('entry_test');
                $this->data['entry_geo_zone']     = $this->language->get('entry_geo_zone');
                $this->data['entry_order_status']   = $this->language->get('entry_order_status');
                $this->data['entry_sort_order']   = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');
                $this->data['entry_custom_header']   = $this->language->get('entry_custom_header');
                $this->data['entry_custom_footer']   = $this->language->get('entry_custom_footer');
                $this->load->model('localisation/order_status');
                $this->data['order_statuses']     = $this->model_localisation_order_status->getOrderStatuses();
                $this->load->model('localisation/geo_zone');
                $this->data['geo_zones']       = $this->model_localisation_geo_zone->getGeoZones();

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_login_id'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_login_id'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_login_id'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_login_id'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_login_id');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_transaction_key'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_transaction_key'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_transaction_key'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_transaction_key'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_transaction_key');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_response_key'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_response_key'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_response_key'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_response_key'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_response_key');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_total'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_total'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_total'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_total'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_total'); 
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_server'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_server'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_server'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_server'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_server');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_test'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_test'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_test'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_test'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_test');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_status'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_status'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_status'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_status'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_status');
                }

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_geo_zone_id'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_geo_zone_id'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_geo_zone_id'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_geo_zone_id'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_geo_zone_id'); 
                } 

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_sort_order'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_sort_order'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_sort_order'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_sort_order'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_sort_order'); 
                } 

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_order_status_id'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_order_status_id'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_order_status_id'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_order_status_id'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_order_status_id'); 
                } 

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_custom_header'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_custom_header'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_custom_header'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_custom_header'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_custom_header'); 
                } 

                if (isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_custom_footer'])) {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_custom_footer'] = $this->request->post['cipg_sim_custom_footer'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['cipg_sim_custom_footer'] = $this->config->get('cipg_sim_custom_footer'); 
                } 

                if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
                  $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
                }

                  if (isset($this->error['login_id'])) {
                  $this->data['error_login_id'] = $this->error['login_id'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['error_login_id'] = '';
                }

                if (isset($this->error['transaction_key'])) {
                  $this->data['error_transaction_key'] = $this->error['transaction_key'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['error_transaction_key'] = '';
                }

                if (isset($this->error['response_key'])) {
                  $this->data['error_response_key'] = $this->error['response_key'];
                } else {
                  $this->data['error_response_key'] = '';
                }

                  $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
                   $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                       'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
                  'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                      'separator' => false
                   );
                   $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                       'text'      => $this->language->get('text_payment'),
                  'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/payment', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                      'separator' => ' :: '
                   );
                   $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                       'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                  'href'      => $this->url->link('payment/cipg_sim', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                      'separator' => ' :: '
                   );
                $this->data['action'] = HTTPS_SERVER .'index.php?route=payment/cipg_sim&token=' . $this->session->data['token'];
                $this->data['cancel'] = HTTPS_SERVER .'index.php?route=extension/payment&token=' . $this->session->data['token'];  
                $this->template = 'payment/cipg_sim.tpl';
                $this->children = array(
                  'common/header',
                  'common/footer'
                );
                $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
              }

              private function validate() {
                /*if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'payment/cipg_sim')){
                  $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
                }
                if (!$this->request->post['cipg_sim_login_id']) {
                  $this->error['login_id'] = $this->language->get('error_login_id');
                }
                if (!$this->request->post['cipg_sim_transaction_key']) {
                  $this->error['transaction_key'] = $this->language->get('error_transaction_key');
                }
                if (!$this->request->post['cipg_sim_response_key']) {
                  $this->error['response_key'] = $this->language->get('error_response_key');
                } elseif(isset($this->request->post['cipg_sim_response_key']) && (strlen(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $this->request->post['cipg_sim_response_key'])) > 20)) {
                  $this->error['response_key'] = $this->language->get('error_response_key');
                }*/
                if (!$this->error) {
                  return TRUE;
                } else {
                  return FALSE;
                }  
              }
            }
            ?>
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: `ControllerPaymentStanbic` does not appear at all in this code. The error message says the error is in stanbic.php, are you sure this is the content of the right file ?

Comment: My apologies, it's supposed to be ControllerPaymentAzNetSim not ControllerPaymentstanbic. I created another file and changed the class name to see. But apparently, I got the same error for both.

Comment: You should edit your question then. Currently it's hard to help you because the error message in the title and in the text is not the correct one. And we know nothing about the `Controller` class. The error message says that the `render()` method is undefined, where is it supposed to defined ? In you class ? In `Controller` ?

Comment: Hi Xebax, I've edited what i wrote initially. Please assist.

Comment: I don't understand, don't you have the error with `render()` anymore ? Don't mix several problems in a single question and don't modify the problem described in your question when you edit it. People will be lost if you do that.

Another thing : your code is very verbose, with a lot of repetitions. Please provide a shorter code that shows your problem. Your question will have more attention and you will have better chances to be helped.

About your problem with `data`, where is this member defined ? In `Controller` ? If not you must define it in your class, like you did for `$error`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using a very recent version of OpenCart. The data attribute is no longer a member of the Controller class, as you can see in the [version history](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/commit/8699e70ecfde3f5ae82f39bc5652e1748f87e732#diff-04279eb38ea27bdc1753be0516b0c269).

I also assume you are using a third-party extension from the Shop. Searching for "stanbic" brings up [one result](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=stanbic), which isn't compatible with any recent OpenCart version.

Try the same extension on an older OpenCart version. Or you can try to fix the implementation yourself:

- Create a local variable `$data = array();` right at the beginning of the index function
- Replace all references to "`$this->data`" with "`$data`"
- Pass the local $data to the setOutput function: `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('foldername/filename.tpl',
  $data))`;

This isnt tested and it is likely that you will have to modify more code, because it appears that the OpenCart 2.x code is quite different from the 1.5.x codebase. Use a [recent controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/controller/payment/globalpay.php) as reference.